# Is there concurrent requests limit for file upload/download using DBRestClient (iOS SDK)?

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there concurrent requests limit for DBRestClient (iOS SDK)? On slower networks when multiple requests for file upload/download issued many of requests fail with error 1001. Any limit recommendations?

While it's possible to build workaround by sequentially uploading/downloading file one by one, this seems overkill especially when multiple requests works fine when network is fast enough.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203301119-iOS-SDK-is-there-concurrent-requests-limit-for-file-upload-download-using-DBRestClient- ]